# How to get the size of a rendered HTML page and not its client size?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to get the size taken up by the elements on an HTML page.
Not the client width of the browser.
As I can't enforce the html to have everything inside a div, because it's user-provided, I need to know that size.
I tried to get the body element size but can't get it. ( tried .width and style.width but neither worked )

Comment: This is pretty tough because a normal unconstrained div goes full width of it's parent.  It doesn't shrink around it's contents.  Perhaps if you could give us a sample of the HTML and describe in more detail what you're trying to measure, we might have a better change of helping.

Comment: Ok forget about the Div, I was just trying to explain. Suppose the page has a table or an image, or both, so the page content takes up some space. I want to know that space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you know specifically which content elements you want to measure and you KNOW that they aren't elastic content elements like a div that go full width regardless of actually content, you can't do this.

If you did know which elements you wanted to measure, you can iterate through all of them get their size and position and accumulate a bounding rect that was the union of all interesting elements.  But if this is arbitrary HTML (as you described it) that you don't know, you can't know the difference between something you care about and an arbitrary container that just goes full width because it does that naturally.

Look at wordwrapping text in a containing div for example.  The containing div goes full width so it will always be full width.  The height of the containing div would be ok to measure, but the width would always be full width and the height would only fit that particular width.  Change the width and the height would be different.

Comment: It's strange that the browser/OS graphics subsystem knows how large a web page is though, it knows when to add horizontal and vertical scroll bars... as long as the web page isn't scaling content on window resize.

Comment: @nmz787 -  The graphics system only knows how big/wide something is when it is given some constraints by either the browser window or the layout instructions of the content.  A browser will only add a horizontal scrollbar when the width of the browser window gets smaller than the smallest that the content layout will allow itself to be.  A stream of text has no "native" size.  It only has a width when someone defines a width for it and then it only has a length when it is flowed into that specific width.  So, someone had to put some constraints on the width in order for it to have some height.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery width() function http://api.jquery.com/width/.

Comment: Ok, suppose I can't use jQuery.

Comment: In most cases, I think offsetHeight and offsetWidth should do the case. Example: http://help.dottoro.com/ljuxqbfx.php

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly for almost every element. Except from html and body, in that case, offsetWidth and offsetHeight return the client size, not the content size.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you used a library like jQuery... Browsers have different ways of reporting widths...

in jQuery you can do this... `$("#divId").width();` and get the pixel width.

More in  http://api.jquery.com/width